# @polkadot/util module issue

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

I got some error when using Polkadot{js} API. what's wrong?
should I update the version of package?

```
import { BN, BN_BILLION, BN_HUNDRED, BN_MILLION, BN_QUINTILL, bnToBn, bnToHex, bnToU8a, formatBalance, formatNumber, hexToBn, isBigInt, isBn, isFunction, isHex, isNumber, isObject, isString, isU8a, u8aToBn, u8aToNumber } from '@polkadot/util';
                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module '@polkadot/util' does not provide an export named 'u8aToNumber'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:123:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:189:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:438:15) {
  page: '/'
}
```

[image]

Comment: I could solve the issue by deleting node_modules and install again

Comment: If deleting your node_modules and installing again worked it was probably a version issue. You can create an answer to your question an mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polkadot-js has a pretty strict dependency tree outline where versions of different `@polkadot/*` packages need to match the root of `@polkadot/api`.

For example:

`@polkadot/api -> v9.14.1` requires `@polkadot/util -> v10.4.1`
So if you are using `v9.14.1` of the API, any package you consume from the [`polkadot-js/common`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common) (i.e. `@polkadot/util-crypto`, `@polkadot/keyring`, etc.) repository should also be `v10.4.1`.

This will ensure that there is no conflict in package versions and the above error won't happen. Also as a side note, updating to the latest version of each package will ensure they match, as releases will be in sync with each other.

Answer (score 1):

all what I had to do was update the version of packages
so if you meet this error, plz try to delete node_module and yarn install again